# Run servlet on glassfish server prompts for master password and run fails

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have written a simple HelloServlet as follows.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class HelloServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/HelloServlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public HelloServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String docType =
        "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 " +
        "Transitional//EN\">\n";
        out.println(docType +
        "<HTML>\n" +
        "<HEAD><TITLE>Hello</TITLE></HEAD>\n" +
        "<BODY BGCOLOR=\"#FDF5E6\">\n" +
        "<H1>Hello</H1>\n" +
        "</BODY></HTML>");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

I have GlassFish 3.1 installed in the Java EE perspective in Eclipse.
Whenever I try and run the servlet clicking on "run on server" on the server it comes up with the following message:

> This domain requires an administrative password to be set before the
>   domain can be started. Please specify an administrative password. The
>   Master Password is required to start the domain.  No console, no
>   prompting possible.  You should either create the domain with
>   --savemasterpassword=true or provide a password file with the --passwordfile option.
>
> Command start-domain failed.

There is always a default master password "changeit" for glassfish. Why is it prompting me with this message ?

[image]